# Adding configuration settings via phpcclib of cloudcontrol

Tags: php, cloudcontrol

Please, I just need to ask if it is possible and how to add configuration settings, similar to this:

```
$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config.add KEY=VALUE
```

via the `phpcclib` of `cloudcontrol`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'config.add' command is implemented in the cctrlapp by adding and removing the custom config add-on and passing along the key-value-pairs. Check out the Python code in [pycclib](https://github.com/cloudControl/cctrl/blob/master/cctrl/app.py#L691) for more details.

The [phpcclib](https://github.com/cloudControl/phpcclib/blob/master/CloudControl/API.php#L524) currently does not pass the required settings parameter along, but it should be easy enough to do so. Pull requests are highly welcome.

Comment: I tried making the pull request, but it seems the REST endpoint for the config.add is not available. as I get the error `no valid json: Gone Method 'POST' not allowed.`